# Python 2.5 for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am having a little trouble understanding this simple for loop code. I just need help explaining why it outputs the way it does.

```
y=0
for x in range(5):
    y=y+x
    print y

>>>
0
1
3
6
10
>>>
```

Comment: 0+1+2+3+4, and parts of that...

Comment: Could you explain a little more please? How the range works? and why it outputs those integers? I know its simple code, just need a little help.

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic for Super User. We have a site dedicated for programming called [SO], but you probably shouldn't post these simple "Here's some code, what does it do?" questions. You need to show us what you already found out, do a little research, et cetera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range(5)` gives you

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

in for loop you add up

```
y(0) = y(0) + x(0) >>> 0
y(1) = y(0) + x(1) >>> 1
y(3) = y(1) + x(2) >>> 3
y(6) = y(3) + x(3) >>> 6
y(10) = y(6) + x(4) >>> 10
```

Comment: Ok I understand the range now. Thanks.